# DllNotFoundException: gInput

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll

I am trying to add Force Feedback in game and installed controller from asset store... But when I start the demo scene, it gives me the error:

```
DllNotFoundException: gInput
GIC.Init (System.String projectName, System.String logFile) (at Assets/GIC/Scripts/GIC.cs:122)
GIC_Loader.Start () (at Assets/GIC/Scripts/GIC_Loader.cs:34)
```

Unity version: 2020.3.10f1

OS: macOS

Also, I tried different dll plugins, same error DllNotFoundException: "plugin name"

DllImport code

```
[DllImport("gInput")]
public static extern int Add10(int a);
```